# API access works in curl but UrlFetchApp returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: google-apps-script, curl, oauth, http-status-code-400, urlfetch

I'm trying to access my Home Assistant API and it works fine using curl, but not in Google Apps Script using UrlFetchApp. Using curl works fine:

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer longFunkyCodeLikeThisiJ9.eyJpc3Mijk5fQ.0Fpw8I" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mydevice.duckdns.org:8123/api/states/sensor.my_special_sensor
```

Google Apps Script returns a 400 Bad Request error.

```
var HOME_ASSISTANT_TOKEN = "longFunkyCodeLikeThisiJ9.eyJpc3Mijk5fQ.0Fpw8I"
var HOME_ASSISTANT_URL = "https://mydevice.duckdns.org:8123/api/"

function testTemp() {
  console.log(getDeviceParameters('sensor.my_special_sensor'));
}

function getDeviceParameters(id) {
  var url = HOME_ASSISTANT_URL + "states/" + id;
  Logger.log(url);
  var bearer = "Bearer " + HOME_ASSISTANT_TOKEN;
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": bearer,
    "Content-Type": 'application/json',
  };
  var params = {
    method: 'get',
    headers: headers
  };
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params ).getContentText();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you examine the duckdns server?

Comment: You don't seem to be `fetch`ing the request at all.  You're using `getRequest`

Comment: @TheMaster I think you misread; `UrlFetchApp` is a class/service/interface that offers several methods including fetch and getRequest. I made no mention of the fetch method.

Comment: `UrlfetchApp.fetch()` is the only method that can make the request.

Comment: @TheMaster I'm not quite sure what you're saying. I see the phrase "this method [getRequest] does not actually issue the request" in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getRequest(String)). However, the function works as expected per my answer below. Googling turns up no information about the difference between the two other than the differing output that is shown in the documentation.

Comment: If the code works or returns 200 or 400, you're not  using `getRequest()` but only `fetch()`. The code in the question does not reflect the code that you're actually running in the script editor.

Comment: @TheMaster alas you're correct. I'm not sure how I ended up with that erroneous code in the original question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Google Apps Script may be blocking port 8123. The script functions by using by instead using your nabu casa url which operates out of port 80.

Just change the `HOME_ASSISTANT_URL` value to `https://[yourspecialcode].ui.nabu.casa/api/`